# GAN generated images all similar per epoch

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, keras, gan

I'm working on a GAN using cifar-10 images.  After each epoch I create 10 new random z noise vectors, and use them to create 10 images using the generator.  All of the 10 images look very similar, but they really shouldn't because the z vectors are all random, and theoretically should be sampling from a broader distribution. It's almost as if the z vector has virtually no influence, and the model creates nearly the same thing regardless of the input. Why would this happen, is this mode collapse?

[image]

Comment: Yes this is mode collapse. What kind of GAN are you training?

Comment: Right now I am just trying to get the simplest possible working, which means no classes or class conditioning, all samples are a single class (boat.)  I am adding .1 noise to the targets so 0.0 to .1 is real, and .9 to 1.0 is generated.  5% of the samples are swapped, real to generated.